# what is the difference between maximum likelihood estimation and usual probability inference?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Can somebody tell me a clear difference between MLE from the usual probability inferences?

Comment: The usual probability inferences being what exactly?

Comment: I am actually trying to understand what MLE is. Somehow, I don't get the clear picture of it. Maybe I don't understand what we need MLE for.

Comment: It's a way of obtaining parameter estimates based on a finite sample.

Comment: If possible, can you give an example?

Comment: Wikipedia has a lot of examples. For instance, the MLE of $\lambda$ in an exponential distribution is derived [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Maximum_likelihood), and the MLE for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ in a normal distribution is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters).

Comment: you said MLE is a way of obtaining parameter estimation based on a finite sample, but if it is binomial probability for a coin-tossing experiment, isn't it the same thing as MLE?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: i think you are missing the point. in real life, you do not know the parameters of the binomial model, hence you need to estimate it...in the real world, you are not given parameters unless you are in fairy tales...you find out the values of parameters based on a sample.

Comment: Just one more thing, why do we use natural log for estimating parameters in MLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of MLE is that you construct a model with certain parameters. However, you do not know the true parameters of the distribution. Hence, you use a sample from the population to **estimate** the parameters. MLE is an estimation method. Here is an example, using the Bernoulli distribution. This time, you are the main character of the story.

"Let's play a game! Flip this coin. If it lands on heads, I win the bet and if it lands on tails, you win the bet. Let's bet ten dollars a round." A game master approached you with this proposal.

"How do I know if the coin you possess is fair?", you asked.

"Test it!"

With that, you receive the coin and attempt to test it. You know that the only possible outcomes are heads and tails, with a probability of, in this case, $p$. Denoting $1$ as heads and $0$ as tails, and letting $X$ be the random variable that the coin will output, you say

$$
X = \begin{cases}0 \text{ with a probability of } p\\1 \text{ with a probability of } 1-p\end{cases}
$$

**This the the formulation of the model.**

Alternatively, if you look at the probability function of the distribution, $f_X(x) = p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$

Remember! At this point, you do not know the **actual** or **true** value of $p$. However, you shall attempt to estimate it. I shall elaborate here and not go to the derivation.

The idea right here is that you **estimate** the value of $p$ based on your sample because you **do not know** the true value. In this case, of course the MLE estimate of $p$ is $\bar x$ however, it is not just a sample mean by elementary statistics! $\bar x$ is the value of $p$ that **maximizes** the likelihood function. The likelihood function, although counter-intuitive, is the **conditional probability** that $p$ takes a certain value **given** the joint probability distribution function. Hence, you see the notation
$L(p) = L(p | x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$.

Consider you toss the coin 5 times and the **sample** values are $1,0,1,1,1$. The likelihood function is actually $$L(p) = p^4(1-p)$$. Attempt to derive this via the pdf of the distribution above.

What you are doing, in MLE, is to find the value of $p$ that **maximizes** this function (that is why you say that value maximizes the likelihood function)...because you want to find the most probable value of $p$ given that you observed this sample.

If you understand this, you can extend this idea to other distributions like the Poisson, or even continuous distributions like the uniform, Gamma or Normal (in this case you have to estimate 2 variables concurrently.)

Remember, in the real world, you do not have the luxury of sampling the whole population which sometimes extends millions or billions (the log returns of a stock might be updated several times a second..so imagine the number of entries you have if you analyze 10 years). Also, you **do not** know the value of the parameters. Beyond this trivial example, consider this:

*You believe that travel time from your home to the city follows a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$ but you do not know the true value of $\lambda$ because it depends on the traffic each day. You want to estimate $\lambda$ so you can plan for your weekly fuel usage. In this case, do you know the true value of $\lambda$? If not, how would you do to **estimate** the value of $\lambda$?*

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe I can go further thanks to your answer.

Comment: In your excellent explanation above, is it possible that there is a small slight of hand when defining the probabilities for 0 and 1? Wouldn't p(1) = p and p(0) = 1 - p be concordant with the rest of the example?

Comment: hi @toni! in your example, the answer would be the same. this is because youre just modifying the expression, not the form. try it!